# Is check_plain() enough?

Tags: security

Is [check_plain()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/check_plain/7) enough for re-displaying the text entered by users in the browser, or should I still filter with [filter_xss()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/filter_xss/7)?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I imagine the question is about using `check_plain(filter_xss($string))`, or `filter_xss(check_plain($string))`.

`check_plain()` and `filter_xss()` have two different, and in contrast, purposes:

- `check_plain()` encodes special characters in a plain-text string that is then displayed as HTML.
- `filter_xss()` filters an HTML string to prevent cross-site-scripting (XSS) vulnerabilities. In particular its purpose is:

  - Removing characters and constructs that can trick browsers
  - Making sure all HTML entities are well-formed
  - Making sure all HTML tags and attributes are well-formed
  - Making sure no HTML tags contain URLs with a disallowed protocol (e.g. javascript:)

If you use `check_plain()`, the string passed to the function is supposed to be used as plain text; in such case, `filter_xss()` is not necessary.
If you use `filter_xss()`, then the string passed to the function is supposed to be HTML, and `check_plain()` is not necessary.

If the question is about using `check_plain()` and `filter_xss()` on different parts of the same string then, as greggles pointed out in his comment, you can use (for example) `check_plain()` on the content of tag attributes, and `filter_xss()` on the entire HTML tag.

Comment: filter_xss is meant to be used on entire pieces of html. If you use filter_xss on an html attribute it will not properly filter it. check_plain can be used to safely filter html attributes. See also http://drupalscout.com/knowledge-base/drupal-text-filtering-cheat-sheet-drupal-6 and http://drupalscout.com/knowledge-base/using-filter-functions-intended-filterxss-and-classes for more info on using these functions.