# Safe string checkup against user-supplied suffix/prefix strings

Tags: theming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is check_plain() enough?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/10280/is-check-plain-enough)

When authoring own plugin/formatter and giving user an option to provide their own HTML prefix and suffix strings , what would be the Drupal way of ensuring safety of those strings?
Would it suffice to `filter_xss` with custom list of allowed tags, or a sequence of some functions would be required?

Answer (score 0):

Treat it like any other user input; that is, not to be trusted. Do you have a reason to allow HTML tags in the prefix/suffix? If not, output only after running through check_plain(). filter_xss() is quite permissive in its allowed tags so just be sure you're OK with that before using. See also the drupal.org [documentation on handling text in a secure way](http://drupal.org/node/28984).